# How to prevent horizontal overflow despite proper width set?

Tags: html, css, frontend

It seems no matter how specifically I define an elements width, it will overflow the document.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
...
<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="navbar-options">
            <div class="navbar-option"><a class="navbar-option-link" href="/home">Home</a></div>
            <div class="navbar-option"><a class="navbar-option-link" href="/news">Newsfeed</a></div>
            <div class="navbar-option"><a class="navbar-option-link" href="/societies">Societies</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="title-box">
        <h1 id="title">Students Of Westminster</h1>
    </div>

</body>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 2.5vw;
    display: flex;
    margin: .5rem;
}
```

[The navbar overflowing, indicated by the horizontal scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ELO.png)

Even with this code, my navbar will overflow the X axis, and even after scrolling till its end, I won't see its margin set on the far right side, how do I fix this?

Comment: use `%` instead of `vw` in your width

Comment: Doesn't work, seems to still overflow

Comment: Can you please add your relevant HTML to accompany your CSS?

Comment: Maybe it's related to the browser? I'm using firefox. Or perhaps the viewport meta tag?

Comment: remove `margin: .5rem;`

Comment: It seems to me that the overflow is coming from somewhere else, because if your navbar is the red one, then the text is centered in the screen. Use the browser tools and check the width of the elements and see which one is greater than the screen

Comment: simply remove width, it's not needed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you describe `width` and `margin` the total width will be width + margin.

If you want your element to have full viewport width including element margin, you could use `calc` to remove 2 * margins.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
    width: calc(100vw - 1rem);
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 2.5vw;
    display: flex;
    margin: .5rem;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar"></div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: but I don't think that would work for all viewports